# Matching for case insensitive exact phrase with spaces

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

If I have a string `"Hello I went to the store today"` and I had an array of matches

```
$perfectMatches = array("i went","store today");
```

It should match both of those. (the array can get quite large so i'd prefer to do it in 1 preg_match)

Edit: Got this one working! thanks!

```
preg_match_all("/\b(" . implode($perfectMatches,"|") . ")\b/i", $string, $match1)
```

I also need a separate regular expression that is kind of hard to explain. Say I have an array

```
$array = array("birthday party","ice cream");//this can be very long
```

Is it possible to get a regular expression that will match a string if "birthday" and "party" and anywhere in the string?

So it should match "Hi, it's my birthday and I'm going to have a party"? But with "ice cream" also in 1 preg_match?

Thanks

Edit: Example...

A user submits a description of an item and I want to check for spam. I know that most spam posts have phrases like "personal checks" or "hot deal" so I want to get a list of all these phrases and check it with the description. If the description has any of the phrases in my list, it'll be marked as spam. This scenario applies to the first regular expression I want.

The second regular expression would be if I knew that some spam posts have the words "lose" "weight" "fast" somewhere in there, doesn't have to be in any order, but those 3 words are in the description. So if I get a list of these phrases "lose weight fast","credit card required" and check it with the description, I can mark it as spam

Comment: Does it have to match both of the "perfectMatches" *in order*?

Comment: Sorry, but I dont understand the question. Can you provide examples ?

Comment: @ExplosionPills order doesn't matter

Comment: In that case it can't be done with a single regex

Comment: The question is a little confusing, but it looks like a regex may make this more confusing than it needs to be. Have you considered a combination of a loop, strpos, and explode?

Comment: @Nate the array could be hundreds of elements and I would need to do this for many items so it would be extremely I/O intensive. I'll add an example so that it's clearer about what I would use this for

Comment: In your question you say the first regular expression will match `"went"`. That's not true. It should do what you want. For the second task, you should use indexing, not regular expressions. A regular expression that matches N words in any order will be O(N^2) in size.

Comment: @explosion-pills, it is possible.  The regex isn't difficult to write, but it is also not very efficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like part 1 of your problem is already solved, so this answer focuses only on part 2.  As I understand it, you are trying to determine if a given input message contains all of a list of words in any order.

This can be done with a regex and a single `preg_match` for each message, but it is very inefficient if you have a large list of words.  If N is the number of words you are searching for and M is the length of the message, then the algorithm should be O(N*M).  If you notice, there are two  `.*` terms in the regex for *each* keyword.  With the lookahead assertions, the regex engine has to traverse once for each keyword. Here is the example code:

```
<?php

// sample messages
$msg1 = "Lose all the weight all the weight you want.  It's fast and easy!";
$msg2 = 'Are you over weight? lose the pounds fast!';
$msg3 = 'Lose weight slowly by working really hard!';

// spam defining keywords (all required, but any order).
$keywords = array('lose', 'weight', 'fast');

//build the regex pattern using the array of keywords
$patt = '/(?=.*\b'. implode($keywords, '\b.*)(?=.*\b') . '\b.*)/is';

echo "The pattern is: '" .$patt. "'\n";
echo 'msg1 '. (preg_match($patt, $msg1) ? 'is' : 'is not') ." spam\n";
echo 'msg2 '. (preg_match($patt, $msg2) ? 'is' : 'is not') ." spam\n";
echo 'msg3 '. (preg_match($patt, $msg3) ? 'is' : 'is not') ." spam\n";
?>
```

The output is:

```
The pattern is: '/(?=.*\blose\b.*)(?=.*\bweight\b.*)(?=.*\bfast\b.*)/is'
msg1 is spam
msg2 is spam
msg3 is not spam
```

This second solution seems more complex because there is more code, but the regex is much simpler.  It has no lookahead assertions and no `.*` terms.  The `preg_match` function is called in a `while` loop, but this is not really a big deal.  Each message is traversed only once and the complexity should be O(M).  This could also be done with a single `preg_match_all` function, but then you would have to perform an `array_search` to get the final count.

```
<?php

// sample messages
$msg1 = "Lose all the weight all the weight you want.  It's fast and easy!";
$msg2 = 'Are you over weight? lose the pounds fast!';
$msg3 = 'Lose weight slowly by working really hard!';

// spam defining keywords (all required, but any order).
$keywords = array('lose', 'weight', 'fast');

//build the regex pattern using the array of keywords
$patt = '/(\b'. implode($keywords,'\b|\b') .'\b)/is';

echo "The pattern is: '" .$patt. "'\n";
echo 'msg1 '. (matchall($patt, $msg1, $keywords) ? 'is' : 'is not') ." spam\n";
echo 'msg2 '. (matchall($patt, $msg2, $keywords) ? 'is' : 'is not') ." spam\n";
echo 'msg3 '. (matchall($patt, $msg3, $keywords) ? 'is' : 'is not') ." spam\n";

function matchall($patt, $msg, $keywords)
{
  $offset = 0;
  $matches = array();
  $index = array_fill_keys($keywords, 0);
  while( preg_match($patt, $msg, &$matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE, $offset) ) {
    $offset = $matches[1][1] + strlen($matches[1][0]);
    $index[strtolower($matches[1][0])] += 1;
  }
  return min($index);
}
?>
```

The output is:

```
The pattern is: '/(\blose\b|\bweight\b|\bfast\b)/is'
msg1 is spam
msg2 is spam
msg3 is not spam
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response! I wasn't very clear in the question so that's my fault, but what if it was `$keywords = array(array("lose","weight","fast"),array("call","now","free"));` and I could do 1 reg_ex and check $msg1 to see if it matched? So with this keyword array, You would get the same output in your example, but it could also catch $msg4 = "Want a free iphone? call now";. If this isn't possible, then I'll have to resort to putting it in a loop, but I would like to avoid that. Thanks again!

Comment: Sure, this can be done with 1 regex, but why?  You say you want to avoid a loop, but it doesn't make sense from a performance standpoint because loops **are** occurring inside the regex.  Just because you don't type `for` doesn't mean the processor isn't iterating.  The best way to do this is to use the indexing method above.  This way, each messaged is only searched once.  For multiple sets of keywords, you will have to compare the index a little differently instead of just using the `min` function, but it is the same concept.

Comment: An example is: `$patt = '/('; foreach($keywords as $group) { $patt = $patt . '(?=.*\b'. implode($group, '\b.*)(?=.*\b') . '\b.*)|'; } echo $patt = substr($patt,0,-1) .')/i';`  For your example, this generates: `/((?=.*\blose\b.*)(?=.*\bweight\b.*)(?=.*\bfast\b.*)|(?=.*\bcall\b.*)(?=.*\bnow\b.*)(?=.*\bfree\b.*))/i`  I'm definitely not recommending that you _use_ this regex, but just saying that it is possible.  Anything is _possible_ in regex.  You could write your entire program as 1 regex, but that does not mean it is a good idea from a performance or readability perspective.